# The most efficient way to change a Groovy file at runtime

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

Right now, I have these three files:

- `PracticeNames`
- `OrganizationNames`
- `PracticeURLs`
- `PracticeProfiles`

that are set up like, for example:

`OrganizationNames.groovy`:

```
public class OrganizationNames {
    public static final String SMD_BETA = "SMD-BETA"
    public static final String PARAGON = "Paragon Private Health Ltd"
}
```

`PracticeNames.groovy`:

```
public final class PracticeNames {
    public static final String IMPERIAL_MEDICAL_CENTER_II = 'Imperial Medical Center II'
    public static final String DEMO_PRACTICE = "Demo practice"

    public static final String PARAGON_DEMO_PRACTICE = "Paragon Demo Practice"

}
```

`PracticeProfiles.groovy`:

```
public final class PracticeProfiles {
    //  TODO: use the Demo Practice URL for this default SMD practice profile
    public static final PracticeProfile SMD_DEFAULT = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.DEMO_PRACTICE, PracticeURLs.PRACTICE_DISCOUNT_TESTS);
    public static final PracticeProfile SMD_IMPERIAL = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.IMPERIAL_MEDICAL_CENTER_II, PracticeURLs.IMPERIAL_MEDICAL_CENTER_II);
    public static final PracticeProfile PARAGON_DEFAULT = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.PARAGON, PracticeNames.PARAGON_DEMO_PRACTICE, PracticeURLs.PARAGON_DEMO_PRACTICE);
}
```

What I want to have happen is, after run of a particular test case (practice creation test case), have some way to update these classes' source code. In other words, on every run of practice creation test case, I'll have the following:

- new practice name
- new practice URL, and from that, using the organization name that was passed in to the test case:
- new practice profile

As you can imagine, this shifts maintenance of those data classes entirely on the person running the test case to create a new practice, which can cause a host of problems down the road.

How can I write these to their respective final classes, using SNAKE_CASE'd practice name as the static field name, at run time?

Comment: Better to store this information to a configuration file - json or yaml. At least you'll not have a question `how to write it`

Comment: How is storing *all the practice names, practice URLs*, ..., to a configuration file going to help?

Comment: "What I want to have happen is, after run of a particular test case (practice creation test case), have some way to update these classes' source code." - FYI... There are a number of complexities you are going to run into if you try to take that approach.  Updating source code while the tests are running is a bad idea. There are better ways to creating dynamic config to support testing different scenarios but there isn't enough info in the question to give a good suggestion, but I would not update source files between tests.